# SSL certificate issue GoDaddy domain , Heroku Server hosting , Cloudflare SSL

Tags: ssl, heroku, cloudflare

I have bought my domain name www.thoughtgrub.com from goDaddy.
However I am hosting it on Heroku. 
I needed an SSL certificate so I set that up using cloudflare.

When I check whether SSL is installed using https://www.digicert.com/help/
It says certificate installed correctly.

However web browser shows www.thoughtgrub.com as unsecure.
also https://thoughtgrub.com --> throws Site cannot be reached error or

shortener.secureserver.net/error_404

What's going wrong?
IS there any other method to achieve https certification?

Comment: So figured I could just have heroku do my ssl and add that domain to godaddy cname. However the ssl for heroku is only available for the paid schemes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to go to heroku settings and click on add SSl certificate.